# Autoscaling GCE Instance groups based on multiple Cloud pub/sub queues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-pubsub, gce-instance-group

I found in the docs to autoscale based on number of undelivered messages in a topic. ([Autoscaling GCE Instance groups based on Cloud pub/sub queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637728/autoscaling-gce-instance-groups-based-on-cloud-pub-sub-queue)).

I want to know if the following scenario is possible:
I have two pub/sub queues and I want to write an autoscaling condition that if any one of the queues has `no_undelivered_messages > 150`, it should scale i.e it should scale `if num_messages in queue1>150 OR num_messages in queue2`.

Please help with this case if it's possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can scale based upon metrics using the AND operator but not the OR operator.

[Per-group metric filtering requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#per_group_metrics)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried this approach but it's not allowing me the same metric twice. Like in my case, I want to use no_undelivered_messages as a metric with two different queues. It's not allowing me.

Comment: You need to create two metrics. One for each queue.